# Сделать внутри программный аналог HOSTS

Tags: c#, .net, dns, httpclient, hosts

Есть необходимость в программе работать с сайтом, чье имя удалено из DNS. Работаю с помощью классов библиотеки System.Net, а именно HttpClient.
При этом сайт отвергает запросы, в которых вместо имени хоста подставлен IP адрес, т.е. в запросе должно фигурировать именно имя хоста. 
Частичное решение моей проблемы - занесение нужной записи в файл Hosts, но мне нужно обеспечить:

1. контроль за обращением к списку Ip адресов соответствующих имени
2. работу в условиях отсутствия админских прав (т.е. невозможности редактировать hosts)

Вопрос: каким образом сделать так, чтоб внутри программы ресолвинг определенных имен перехватить и делать самому?

Comment: Напишите метод, меняющий host и все свои uri передавайте не напрямую, а через этот метод

Comment: Серверу обычно не важно, что и как разрешается на локальной машине. Нужно просто прописать что-то вроде `httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Host", "example.com");`, тогда запрос будет неотличим

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, в  url сохраняю имя сервера, в Host пишу IP адрес - результат 400 ошибка. 
Если наоборот подменить в url адрес на IP, а в хост прописать имя - вылетает System.Net.Http.CurlException: Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates

Comment: @АндрейNOP можете показать как это сделать? свойство Host у class Uri - readonly

Comment: `new Uri(uri.Scheme + "://" + newHost + (uri.IsDefaultPort ? "" : ":" + uri.Port) + uri.PathAndQuery + uri.Fragment)`

Comment: Если тут еще SSL-аутентификация замешана, и все это под Net Core, тогда легко способа точно нет. Либо hosts, либо поднимать свой DNS.

Comment: Если вас на самом деле не волнует аутентификация, есть какой-то костыль на это исключение: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43256337/how-to-ignore-system-net-http-curlexception-peer-certificate-cannot-be-authent

Answer (score 5):

Имеется [библиотека](https://github.com/kapetan/dns), которая позволяет создавать прокси DNS сервер в самом C# приложении, который может перехватывать все запросы и направлять их на нужные адреса. [Здесь](https://github.com/kapetan/dns#server) имеется пример создания прокси DNS сервера.

Приведу пример использования библиотеки:

```
class Program
{
    static DnsServer _proxyServer;

    static string _testDomain = "my.blablablakons.com";
    static string _redirectIp = "127.0.0.1";
    static string _realDnsServer = "8.8.8.8";

    static Task StartProxyServer()
    {
        // Proxy to google's DNS
        MasterFile masterFile = new MasterFile();
        // Resolve these domain to localhost
        //masterFile.AddIPAddressResourceRecord("blablablakons.com", _redirectIp);
        masterFile.AddIPAddressResourceRecord(_testDomain, "127.0.0.1");
        _proxyServer = new DnsServer(masterFile, _realDnsServer);

        // Log every request
        //_proxyServer.Requested += (request) => Console.WriteLine(request);
        _proxyServer.Responded += (request, response) => Console.WriteLine("{0} => {1}", request, response);
        //_proxyServer.Listening += () => Console.WriteLine("Listening started");
        //_proxyServer.Errored += (e) => {
        //    Console.WriteLine("Errored: {0}", e);
        //    ResponseException responseError = e as ResponseException;
        //    if (responseError != null) Console.WriteLine(responseError.Response);
        //};

        // Start the server (by default it listents on port 53)
        return _proxyServer.Listen();
    }


    static async void Do(object data)
    {
        CancellationToken token = (CancellationToken)data;
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri($"http://{_testDomain}"));
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task listenTask = StartProxyServer();

        // Start thread for send requests
        CancellationTokenSource cs = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Thread requestThr = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Do));
        requestThr.Start(cs.Token);

        Console.WriteLine("All started");

        Console.ReadLine();

        cs.Cancel();
        requestThr.Join();

        _proxyServer.Dispose();
        listenTask.Wait();
    }
}
```

Суть работы примера:
1. Создается proxy-сервер, который публикуется на `localhost` по порту `53`(порт по-умолчанию). При создании DNS сервера, основным(реальным) dns-сервером указываем адрес `_realDnsServer(8.8.8.8)`. Те DNS имена, которые не будут найдены в нашем прокси DNS сервере, будут отправляться на этот указанный dns сервер
2. Прописываем для прокси сервера правило резолва требуемого DNS имени(`_testDomain = "my.blablabla.com"`) на некий ip-адрес(`_redirectIp = "127.0.0.1"`), куда вы хотите отправлять запросы
3. В настройках операционной системы добавляем адрес нашего публикуемого прокси сервера (для простоты, я в настройках сетевого адаптера оставил один DNS адрес 127.0.0.1) 
4. Все запросы к нашему DNS серверу логгируем `_proxyServer.Requested += (request) => Console.WriteLine(request);`
5. Запускаем поток, который раз в 1 секунду с помощью класса HttpClient делает GET запросы по DNS имени *my.blablablakons.com*.

Запускаем приложение. 
Попытаемся открыть какую-нибудь страницу в браузере.
При открытии страницы в браузере видим, что запрос по получению IP адреса открываемой страницы был проксирован через наш опубликованный сервер.
Попытаемся открыть страницу *my.blablablakons.com*. Видим отображение страницы, которую указали в резолве.

Таким образом, вы можете гибко из своего приложения управлять, на какие ip-адреса должны уходить ваши запросы, делая запрос по DNS-имени.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный развернутый ответ!
К сожалению, это не совсем то, что нужно. Что параметры DNS на уровне операционной системы править нужны права администратора. При их наличии HOSTS отредактировать проще. 
Ну и в обоих случаях получаются изменения глобально на всю систему. А мне нужно только внутри приложения взять под контроль ресолвинг имен.

Comment: При правке файла HOSTS вам нужны привилегированные права на все время работы приложения, плюсом само приложение необходимо запускать с привилегированными правами. В случае же этого варианта, **вам не нужны права администратора** внутри приложения и **приложение не должно запускаться от админа**. Чувствуете разницу. Вам только необходимо поставить корректно вашу программу. А программу поставить в ОС без админских прав - это из мира "хаоса", в котором пользователи бы творили все что угодно в ОС.

Comment: Поставить программу корректно - это зарезервировать порт публикации прокси DNS сервера, добавить в настройки системы DNS адрес, установить файлы в систему. Для этого нужны админские права.

Comment: Ставить программу - такого варианта нет в моей задаче. Увы :( Да и сложнее он, чем разово отредактировать HOSTS до запуска моего приложения. 
Тут вопрос: могу ли я внутри своей запущенной программы сказать: "Обращаемся не к DNS прописанному в ОС, а к внутренеему" ?

Comment: Та программа, в рамках которой возникла задача, ее ставить не надо. Достаточно пользовательских прав на запуск. идет как portable. И за эти ограничения я не могу выйти.

Comment: Ставить программу - такого варианта нет в моей задаче. Задача установки программы - это задача естественно админа, а не программиста. @AlekseyPetrov, я вас понимаю, что вы хотите... Но, но, думаю так нельзя.

Comment: нет ли в app.config или параметрах HttpClient возможности поуправлять обращениями к Dns?

Comment: у вас понимаете в чем проблема, если просто вычислить ip адрес по домену - это не проблема, сходил к DNS имени, он вернет ip. Вам же нужно чтобы сетевой запрос ушел именно с DNS именем и там внутри где-то на уровне ОС срезолвился. В app.config я не встречал ничего такого.